# What exactly happens when a redis command like 'get' is executed?

Tags: redis

I read that the redis client creates a byte string for the get command and passes it to the server which processes the command.
How does the server process the command? Which functions in what order are called? Can someone be elaborate please?

Comment: http://redis.io/topics/protocol

Comment: Here's a somewhat oldish but still very relevant description: https://pauladamsmith.com/blog/2011/03/redis_get_set.html

Comment: The source is on github and easy to read. That would seem the best way to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great article https://pauladamsmith.com/articles/redis-under-the-hood.html that explains the processing of command. The command is converted into byte string, and sent to the server queue, which picks it up, executes, appends an error flag if wrong no of args are passed, and returns the result. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is better if you know something about gdb(http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/)

you can add a break point in main function in Redis and then send a get command to see what happened.

A good idea is that you know epoll or select or kqueue.